# Can't Integrate Solr with Nutch

Tags: apache, hadoop, solr, nutch

I crawl the data from Nutch to be but have not put the data displayed on Solr.
How to integrate Solr with Nutch?
[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sicA4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with SOLR but is due to the fact that the segments have not been parsed.  Use the crawl script, it will run the steps in the right order.